# Difference between DatagridView.CurrentCell and DatagridView.SelectedCells(0) if DatagridView.SelectedCells.Count =1

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

Is there any difference between `DatagridView.CurrentCell` and `DatagridView.SelectedCells(0)` if the `DatagridView.SelectedCells.Count = 1` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current cell is the cell in which you [have your focus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can move focus using Tab. [Selected cells is part of collection of highlighted cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But only one cell can have focus. Being highlighted doesn't mean to have focus. If your grid has more than one cell selected - `DatagridView.SelectedCells.Count > 1`. The index of collections usually starts with 0. So, if you have 2 cells selected, first cell will be `DatagridView.SelectedCells(0)`, second - `DatagridView.SelectedCells(1)`

Answer (score 0):

T.S. is correct however there is one additional thing you have to understand. SelectedCells collection is not necessarily in row/cell order. If the user clicks top-left to right-bottom then they will be in row/cell order. However if the user clicks upward or right to left then collection will not be in order, and SelectedCells[0] might not be referencing the one you want.